# How to properly implement member and non-member functions with templates in C++?

Tags: c++, oop

I am learning object-oriented programming on my own. I am trying to implement a templated class. I am getting some linking error which I don't understand. My implementation is given below.

The `Point.h` contains a declaration of a Point class.

```
//Point.h
#pragma once
template <typename T>
class Point
{
        public:
                T x,y;
                Point();
                Point(T , T);
                Point(const Point<T>& P);
};

template <typename T>
Point<T> operator+ (const Point<T> & P1, const Point<T> & P2);
```

The member functions of `Point` class is implemented in `Point.cpp`

```
//Point.cpp
#include "Point.h"
template <typename T>
Point<T>::Point()
{}

template <typename T>
Point<T>::Point(T _x, T _y)
{
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
}

template <typename T>
Point<T>::Point(const Point<T> & P)
{
        x = P.x;
        y = P.y;
}

template <typename T>
Point<T> operator+ (const Point<T> & P1, const Point<T> & P2)
{
        Point<T> P3;
        P3.x = P1.x + P2.x;
        P3.y = P1.y + P2.y;
        return P3;
}
```

Now, I am testing the file in `test-1.cpp`.

```
//test-1.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Point.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        Point<double> A(0,0), B(1,1), C;
        C = A+B;
        cout << C.x << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile the `test-1.cpp` as

```
g++ Point.cpp test-1.cpp
```

It gives some linking error,

```
/usr/sbin/ld: /tmp/cccV74gb.o: in function `main':
test-1.cpp:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `Point<double>::Point(double, double)'
/usr/sbin/ld: test-1.cpp:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `Point<double>::Point(double, double)'
/usr/sbin/ld: test-1.cpp:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `Point<double>::Point()'
/usr/sbin/ld: test-1.cpp:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to `Point<double> operator+<double>(Point<double> const&, Point<double> const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What disturbs me most is the last error, where the compiler looks for `+ < double >` operator
which I never defined. I have only overloaded `+` operator.

How to properly implement member and non-member functions with templates?

Comment: Note that there are no such beasts as "templated classes". There are class templates.

Comment: The source of templates must be visible when the instantiation happens. Move all template stuff from .cpp to .h.

Comment: `double` in `operator+<double>` is for `T = double`.